# interpolating values on 2D plane for planes of same bounding box but different mesh structure

Tags: python, c++, package, interpolation, linear-algebra

I have simulated data provided on a computational mesh at each intersecting mesh line (i.e. node) and want to interpolate that onto a new 2D plane that has the same dimension (i.e. they both have the same bounding box) but for post-processing reasons I need a cartesian mesh rather than an arbitrary curvilinear one. The figure below demonstrates the problem (the top mesh is where I have my computational data available and the bottom mesh is where I want to interpolate those values onto)

[image]

The gap in the top image (i.e. where no information is available) can simply be filled with zeros or -1 on the interpolated plane (bottom image), indicate that no values are available here.

The data for the computational data (top image) is available as essentially CSV data, e.g. (for a 2D plane orientated in the x-y plane between xmin = 0, ymin = 0, xmax = 1, ymax = 5)

```
x, y, z, data_1, data_2, ..., data_n
0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.7, ..., 0.9
0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 1.1, 1.3, ..., 1.2
0.2, 0.0, 0.0, 1.3, 1.1, ..., 1.3
..., ..., ..., ..., ..., ..., ...
1.0, 5.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.3. ..., 0.6
```

However, given the figure above, the data entries in x and y may not always be sorted.

My question now is if there is a package/library that can perform this sort of interpolation (rather than having to reinvent the wheel)? I am flexible on languages but would prefer c++ / python if there was a choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python you can use [scipy.interpolate.griddata](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html#scipy.interpolate.griddata). This accepts unstructured data and interpolates it onto a given points:

```py
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
import numpy as np

# Generate some xy coordinates at random positions and some values at each coordinate:
xy = [(x, y) for x, y in np.random.random((100, 2))]
v = [(x - y, x+y) for x, y in xy]  # Note - v can have more than 1 dimension if desired

# Define a grid:
grid = [(x, y) for x in np.linspace(0, 1, 21) for y in np.linspace(0, 1, 21)]

# Interpolate v onto the grid
interpolated = griddata(xy, v, grid)

# interpolated[n] is the value at the position grid[n], for example
# grid[50] = 0.1, 0.4
# interpolated[5] = [-0.3, 0.5] ( = 0.1-0.4, 0.1+0.4)
```

In your case you need to be aware that `griddata` will interpolate in the gap on your mesh - the values won't be 0 or 1, they'll be whatever interpolation between the points surrounding the gap yields.